# Vscode doesn't automatically change the color of keywords even if they are captured sucessfully with my own extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to develop a VScode extension to adapt my own language.

VScode has already captured the comments and the keywords, as the picture shows, but only the color of comments is automatically changed, while that of keywords are not.
[image]

This is the syntaxes .json

```
"scopeName": "source.rosita",
"fileTypes": ["rosita"],
"name": "rosita",
"patterns": [
    {   "include": "#comments"  },
    {   "include": "#keywords"  }
],
"repository": {
    "comments": {
        "comment": "% comment",
        "patterns": [
            {
                "name" : "comment.rosita",
                "match": "%.*"
            }
        ]
    },
    "keywords": {
        "patterns": [
            {
                "name" : "keywords.general.rosita",
                "match": "\\b(?:GIDIR|GODIR|GTDIR)\\b"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Could somebody explain what's going on?

Comment: use `keyword.general.rosita`, one word can't be a `keywords`

Comment: why use a `repository`, you can use the patterns directly no need to include